# Failing to populate the Options in Select element using javascript

Tags: javascript

The following code is able to generate the Select drop down list but it is not being populated with options.  I am trying to create a 'day of the month' calendar.  I am not sure where my code is wrong...

```
 var select_day = document.createElement('select');
 select_day.setAttribute('id', 'select_day');

 var dayArray = []; // populate day array
              for(var i=0; i <= 30; i++){
                    dayArray[i] = i + 1;
            }
 console.log(dayArray);

 // DATE - create and append options
 for(var i=0; i< dayArray.length; i++){
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.setAttribute('value', dayArray[i]);
    option.setAttribute('text', dayArray[i]);
    select_day.appendChild(option);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute that controls (in the absence of a child text node) the display text of an option is called `label`, not `text`.

> ```
> option.setAttribute('text', dayArray[i]);
> ```

should be

```
option.setAttribute('label', dayArray[i]);
```

```js
var select_day = document.createElement('select');
 select_day.setAttribute('id', 'select_day');

 var dayArray = []; // populate day array
 for (var i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
   dayArray[i] = i + 1;
 }
 console.log(dayArray);

 // DATE - create and append options
 for (var i = 0; i < dayArray.length; i++) {
   var option = document.createElement('option');
   option.setAttribute('value', dayArray[i]);
   option.setAttribute('label', dayArray[i]);
   select_day.appendChild(option);
 }

 document.body.appendChild(select_day);
```